# how to redirect page after validation

Tags: javascript, html, window

how to redirect page after validation
here is my code :

function checkSubmit(){

```
    var nameValue = localStorage.getItem("username");
     var passValue = localStorage.getItem("psw");
     var gendreValue=localStorage.getItem("check");
     var nameInput= document.getElementById("username");
      var passInput= document.getElementById("psw");
     if(nameInput.value == nameValue && passInput.value == passValue) {
    //alert('You are loged in successfully.');
         window.location.replace("quiz.html");
}else {
    alert('Please enter valid name and password');
}
```

}

Comment: what is the problem in this line .. window.location.replace("quiz.html"); ??!

Comment: window.location.replace("quiz.html"); this line seems functionable but what error do you get?

Comment: the issue is when i click submit it didn't redirect to quiz.html it just put username and pass in the url like this http://localhost:8080/LoginForm.html?username=ahmed&psw=Ahmed20

Comment: window.location = 'http://localhost/quiz.html' , can you try that code if it works

Comment: thank you but didn't work with me .. i solved by by giving my form in html action +my demand url and i changed this in js .. my code >> if (nameInput.value == nameValue && passInput.value == passValue) {
                alert('You are loged in successfully.');

            } else {
                alert('Please enter valid name and password');
                document.getElementById("myform").action = 'LoginForm.html';
            }

        } is this the best way ?!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to webpages use: `window.location.href = "quiz.html";` (that is for javascript)

For example in your html page put: `<script> window.location.href = "quiz.html"; </script>`

For the html code use: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="time; URL=quiz.html" />`

Replace `quiz.html` with the page or website you want it to redirect you to.

Comment: thank you but didn't work with me .. i solved by by giving my form in html action +my demand url and i changed this in js .. my code >> if (nameInput.value == nameValue && passInput.value == passValue) {
                alert('You are loged in successfully.');

            } else {
                alert('Please enter valid name and password');
                document.getElementById("myform").action = 'LoginForm.html';
            }

        } is this the best way ?!

Comment: Yes, I believe so.